# Android App does not open through schema (default/chrome browsers)

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-studio, schema

I have searched google every where to find a solution for 'Android App does not open through schema (default/chrome browsers)'. But I could not find a proper solution.

Below code set I added to Android Manifest.xml to link schema with browser.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="com.qa-soft.team" />
                android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.qa-soft.team" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but when I access ( com.qa-soft.team://OPENPDF-INDEX.pdf ) through default/chrome browser, it will be redirected to google search.
Anyhow when I access through firefox browser, it is working fine. (load the app activity)

what is the real issue for this and how can I overcome it?

Comment: "when I access ( com.qa-soft.team://OPENPDF-INDEX.pdf ) through default/chrome browser" -- how are you doing this? If you are typing it in the address bar, try a link. Overall, though, browsers are not obligated to look for `ACTION_VIEW` activities for URLs.

Comment: I just typed the url (com.qa-soft.team://OPENPDF-INDEX.pdf) on browser and it worked for firefox but deault/ chrome browsers. when I use <a href="com.qa-soft.team://OPENPDF-INDEX.pdf">Test link</a>  html, It worked for all browser.

Comment: Same this I did for Objective C and it is working fine.

Comment: There *really* is no requirement for a browser to check for `ACTION_VIEW` implementations for an address typed in the browser.